# Connecting Blackberry Devices

Tags: sockets, blackberry, connection

I need to create a blackberry application that connects two phones for information exchange. One of these phones should support several incoming connections at the same time and serve them all. The other phones should not see any other phones except the central one.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Connecting through sockets? Data Services? Internet? What would be the advantages/disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To asses the advantages and disavantages of each method one would really need to know the full requirments of you project. That said though, I would suggest you look at the [BlackBerry Messenger SDK](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/blackberrymessenger/). The SDK nicely abstracts away all the issues with mobile-to-mobile communications.

Comment: The satellite phones should connect to the central through a given variable address. The central phone should be able to send individual messages and broadcasts and files as well.